# Missing C library error during stack build with nix

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, nix

In my project I'm using a library that depends on two C packages: `sqlite3` and `libsqlite3-dev`. I installed them using `apt-get install` and then build the project with `stack build` and everything works fine.

However, the `stack build` fails when used with nix with error message "* Missing C library: sqlite3". I understand that the nix enviroment is isolated and that I have to install it there. I tried installing it using `nix-env -i sqlite3` but it returns `error: selector ‘sqlite3’ matches no derivations`. It looks it is missing in the channel (using nixpkgs-unstable).

Is there any way how use to use C libraries with stack and nix that are missing in the channel?

I am using nix because of a [bug in IHaskell](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell/issues/741), otherwise I would be fine with just stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `sqlite` to your packages section in `stack.yaml` as follows:

```
nix:
  enable: false
  packages:
    - sqlite
```

The `enable: false` is there so that Stack doesn't try to build with Nix by default. If you want this behaviour, remove that line.

There's an example of this [here](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell/blob/b0b5236d684757b021b58fcea3719a00b708831d/stack.yaml#L23-L35).